# How to compile all included files into one using Babel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am using Babel in my project. The thing is, I have this line of code in my `server.js`:

```
import schema from "./data/schema";
```

(`data/schema.js` is in ES2015 syntax).

And when I am trying to compile my `server.js` with babel, like this:

```
babel -o server_production.js --minified  server.js
```

it produces a new file without errors and replaces `import` instruction with `require`. But the thing is, when I am trying to run my babel-compiled `server.js` with `node`, it complains about `data/schema.js`, because it wasn't transpiled into ES5, only required (the exact error is `Unexpected token "import"`, because I am using some other imports in `data/schema.js`).

So, the question is: how can I compile my file and all the files it `import`s into one file? I tried `babel -o server_production.js --minified data/schema.js server.js`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I don't think Babel does dependency analysis. You have to specify all the files you want to convert.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Babel doesn't bundle dependencies by default. You'll need to use a module bundler like [rollup](http://rollupjs.org/).

To do this, you'll need to define a `rollup` config similar to this one:

**rollup.config.js**

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import babelrc from 'babelrc-rollup';

export default {
  entry: 'server.js',
  dest: 'server_production.js',
  plugins: [
    babel(babelrc())
  ]
};
```

This works with the `package.json` file defined below:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "rollup": "./node_modules/.bin/rollup -c"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.14.0",
    "babel-plugin-external-helpers": "6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.14.0",
    "babelrc-rollup": "3.0.0",
    "rollup": "0.35.10",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "2.6.1"
  }
}
```

You execute the command `npm run rollup -c` to bundle and compile the files.

You'll find an example here: https://ide.c9.io/ifeanyidev/babel-rollup-example

Comment: `npm run rollup` is sufficient

Comment: Anyone have updates to this process for Babel 7? Specifically, the `rollup.config.js` expects different attributes and `babel-plugin-external-helpers` is no longer compatible

Comment: So happy to finally find someone trying the same thing only to be disappointed with a 3 year old and possibly very outdated answer.

Comment: i got `[!] Error: You must supply options.input to rollup`

Answer (score -8):

You can use the following solution to compile all included files into one using Babel:

```
npx babel src --out-file script-compiled.js
```

Comment: This will either compile a single file to another single file, or compile all files in the same directory into a single file. You copied it from the @babel-cli site without understanding anything about the subject.