# How to compile multiple javascript files that depends on each other into one single output file by using Babel?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have the two following simple Javascript files:

#### lib.js

```
export function increment(x) {
    return x + 1;
}
```

#### main.js

```
import {increment} from "./lib";
console.log(increment(1));
```

As you can see `main.js` imports `lib.js` to use the `increment` function, here the ES6 modules syntax has been used.

I would like to know **if there is a way to compile these two files into a single output file by using Babel**?
Given that I use the following `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": ["env"],
    "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
}
```

I have been able to compile the files with the following command: `babel lib.js main.js` which produces the following:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
exports.inc = inc;
function inc(x) {
    return x + 1;
}
"use strict";

var _lib = require("./lib");

console.log(lib.inc(1));
```

The generated code seem to depend upon the require library and on the fact that the files are separated (not concatenated).

What I would like to have is the following:

```
"use strict";

function inc(x) {
    return x + 1;
}

console.log(inc(1));
```

Is this supported by babel?

Comment: No, Babel is not a packer. Use rollup, webpack or any other library designed to create bundles.

Comment: This isn't a job for Babel. Use Webpack/Browserify/Rollup.

Comment: You can use Rollup, This might be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471896/how-to-compile-all-included-files-into-one-using-babel